# Mullvad connection breaks after short period on debian 11 and 12

Tags: debian, networking, vpn

On Debian 10, `mullvad-vpn` worked fine. But from Debian 11 on, I got an error (maybe) related to DNS. After startup and connection, just a few internet addresses can be solved (within a short periot) before the browsers gives a connection error.

Already resolved addresses can be found in a new tab again and again. As described in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/265376/problem-with-dns-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-mullvad-vpn), I can ping `8.8.8.8` all the time but cannot open `www.google.com`.

Mullvad shows a proper connection all the time, the little lock symbol on the WiFi icon in the system tray and the green lock.

I tried to use wireguard with the mullvad config but this resulted in the same phenomenon.

I am using a Thinkpad x61s with bookworm, kernel 6.1.0-11-rt-amd64 und xfce.